# response.Error "Forbidden" in IdentityServer3 Flows.ClientCredentials

Tags: c#, openid, access-token, identityserver3, client-certificates

I'm having a Client in my IdentityServer3

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "Client Credentials Flow Client With Certificate",
    Enabled = true,
    ClientId = "cc.WithCertificate",
    Flow = Flows.ClientCredentials,

    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
        {
            new Secret
            {
                Value = "61B754C541BBCFC6A45A9E9EC5E47D8702B78C29",
                Type = Constants.SecretTypes.X509CertificateThumbprint,
                Description = "Client Certificate"
            },
        },

    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
        {
            "read"
        }
},
```

In Client Windows Form application I'm using "Client.pfx" downloaded from the URL https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/ClientCertificateConsoleClient/Client.pfx

The Client Certificate has the ThumbPrint

```
Thumbprint = "61B754C541BBCFC6A45A9E9EC5E47D8702B78C29"
```

The Client Code is

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2("Client.pfx");

var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

string tokenEndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenEndpoint"];

var client = new TokenClient(
    tokenEndPoint,
    "cc.WithCertificate",
    handler);

// Calling the Token Service
var response = client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("read").Result;
```

I did the configuration as specified in https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/clientCerts.html

```
<location path="core/connect/token">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Initially its gives me the `Internal Server Error`, later I changed the following mode to "**`Allow`**"

File Path: `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

```
<section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

to

```
<section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Later its the response is coming with an Error Status Code: `response.Error ="Forbidden"`

Here with I have attached the Snapshot of Response Object

[image]

Kindly assist me how to fix this issue and get the AccessToken using ClientCertificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the "**`Client.pfx`**" Certificate in the Client side and your are passing the same to the IdentityServer through `HTTP Request`.

The said certificate has a Root Certificate namely "**`DevRoot`**", it should be in the said `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` otherwise the **IIS** should not allow the request and return back with status code **`403 Forbidden`**.

Kindly have a look into the snapshot and it shows the information of "**`Client.pfx`**"

[image]

So, ensure the "**`DevRoot`**" is installed in the "`Trusted Root Certification Authorities`"

[image]

If not there kindly download the "**`DevRoot.cer`**" and Import the same in the said path (i.e., `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`).

DevRoot.cer download URL: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Certificates/DevRoot.cer

Comment: I facing the same issue while working with Self Signed Client Certificate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923170/issue-in-self-signed-client-certificate-while-processing-an-identity-server-clie