# Getting access token with client credentials and X509 certificate (Identity Server 4)

Tags: identityserver4, x509certificate

i'm looking for a solution for 4 days but i have found nothing.
What i want is to get an access token from my Identity Server with a `client_credentials` `grant_type`. I found that you can do this but nowhere is explained how to make the certificates, how the request is made etc.
I tried a lot of ways but with no success.
*From the documentation:Our default private key JWT secret validator expects the full (leaf) certificate as base64 on the secret definition. This certificate will then be used to validate the signature on the self-signed JWT* . That base64 is the content of the .cert file i believe. On the request should i put the .pfx file in base64 too?

Are there any changes that i need to make on the `program.cs` file for the Kestrel? I found this too, but all are outdated and doesn't work.

Now i'm trying with postman, after this everything should be called from an Azure Logic App.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923170/issue-in-self-signed-client-certificate-while-processing-an-identity-server-clie) example : but doesn't work.
The error:
[image]

Postman:
[image]
[image]

Program.cs
[image]

And the Config.cs from Identity
[image]

I will be very glad if you can help. Thanks in advance

Comment: what would you like to achieve? the post you referenced used the client cert for authenticating **user** based on Client Certificate. where that can be applied? in internal banking software where each user has his own hardware token or something like that. most common practice is to use machine wide client cert to authenticate a **client**, and that's totally outside the scope of IdSrv. as you mention client_creds, there is now user at all. so just follow the post I referenced yesterday, avoid touching the IdSrv and that's it.

Comment: I think you're a bit confused. The client_credentials call is very straightforward (https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/), and as comment above says this isn't a **user** authentication but a machine/client authentication. You just need to provide the client_id and client_secret.

Comment: @d_f client validates server + server validates client = MTLS. Using this concept we can acheive Proof-of-Possesion tokens

Comment: @prison-mike you are right, but MTLS usually lives separately from oauth and jwt. Wcf offered that out of the box, while the benefit of OAuth is simplicity. Anyway the reason for OP to write this post was in some other (and I can't recall it today).

Answer (score -2):

As said you can use a client secret instead of a client certificate which is more common/easier. If you really need certificate authentication: I found more information on http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/mtls.html